# Find category's parameter's and combine them in the right order

Tags: c#, parameters, categories, revit-api

This code filters elements of certain category and finds and concatenates parameters although what needed is something a little more complex.
First of all, a person needs to be able to choose a category (out of a drop down list) or search and find the necessary ones.
And the second thing is that a user is supposed to specify what parameters he would like to combine (we have shared parameters txt fyi) and choose the order in which they are going to follow one another. Any resource on it or something similar to it would help greatly!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Autodesk.Revit.DB;
using Autodesk.Revit.UI;
using Autodesk.Revit.Attributes;
using Autodesk.Revit.UI.Selection;

namespace CombineParameters  
{
    [Transaction(TransactionMode.Manual)]
    public class Class : IExternalCommand
    {

     public Result Execute(ExternalCommandData commandData, 
                           ref string message, 
                           ElementSet elements)
        
        {
            UIApplication uiapp = commandData.Application;
            UIDocument uidoc = uiapp.ActiveUIDocument;
            //Application app = uiapp.Application;
            Document doc = uidoc.Document;

            //Create Filtered Element Collector and Filter
            FilteredElementCollector collector = new FilteredElementCollector(doc);

            ElementCategoryFilter filter = new ElementCategoryFilter(BuiltInCategory.OST_DuctFitting);

            //Applying Filter

            IList <Element> ducts = collector.WherePasses(filter).WhereElementIsNotElementType().ToElements();



            foreach (Element e in ducts)
            {
                //Get Parameter values
                string parameterValue1 = e.LookupParameter("AA").AsString();
                string parameterValue2 = e.LookupParameter("BB").AsString();
                string parameterValue3 = e.LookupParameter("CC").AsString();

                string newValue = parameterValue1 + "-" + parameterValue2 + "-" + parameterValue3;
                
                using (Transaction t = new Transaction(doc, "Set Parameter name"))
                {
                    t.Start();
                  
                    e.LookupParameter("DD").Set(newValue).ToString();
                    
                    t.Commit();
                }

            }

            return Result.Succeeded;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to combine user selected parameters in a specific order? Why dont you use a simple windows form gui.

Example

command.cs

```
#region Namespaces
using Autodesk.Revit.ApplicationServices;
using Autodesk.Revit.Attributes;
using Autodesk.Revit.DB;
using Autodesk.Revit.UI;
using Autodesk.Revit.UI.Selection;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;

#endregion

namespace combineParameters
{
    [Transaction(TransactionMode.Manual)]
    public class Command : IExternalCommand
    {
        public Result Execute(
          ExternalCommandData commandData,
          ref string message,
          ElementSet elements)
        {
            UIApplication uiapp = commandData.Application;
            UIDocument uidoc = uiapp.ActiveUIDocument;
            Application app = uiapp.Application;
            Document doc = uidoc.Document;

            Form1 form = new Form1(doc);
            //Show Dialouge form 
            form.ShowDialog();

            return Result.Succeeded;
        }
    }
}
```

Forms1.cs

```
using Autodesk.Revit.DB;
using Autodesk.Revit.UI;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace combineParameters
{
    public partial class Form1 : System.Windows.Forms.Form
    {
       //Class variable 
        Document revitDoc { get; set; } 
        public Form1(Document doc)
        {
            
            InitializeComponent();
            
            this.revitDoc = doc;
            //Create a list of the parameters you want your user to choose from 
            List<string> stringParameters = new List<string>
            {
                "textParameter1",
                "textParameter2",
                "textParameter3",
                "textParameter4"
            };
            //Add list to comboboxes on form 
            foreach (string parameterName in stringParameters)
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Insert(0, parameterName);
                comboBox2.Items.Insert(0, parameterName);
                comboBox3.Items.Insert(0, parameterName);
            }

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            FilteredElementCollector collector = new FilteredElementCollector(revitDoc);

            ElementCategoryFilter filter = new ElementCategoryFilter(BuiltInCategory.OST_DuctFitting);

            //Applying Filter

            IList<Element> ducts = collector.WherePasses(filter).WhereElementIsNotElementType().ToElements();

            using (Transaction t = new Transaction(revitDoc, "Set Parameter name"))
            {
                //Use a try and catch for transactions
                try
                {
                    t.Start();
                    foreach (Element duct in ducts)
                    {
                        //Get Parameter values
                        string parameterValue1 = duct.LookupParameter(comboBox1.Text).AsString();
                        string parameterValue2 = duct.LookupParameter(comboBox2.Text).AsString();
                        string parameterValue3 = duct.LookupParameter(comboBox3.Text).AsString();

                        string newValue = parameterValue1 + "-" + parameterValue2 + "-" + parameterValue3;

                        //do not need .ToString() when setting parameter
                        duct.LookupParameter("NewParameter").Set(newValue);
                    }
                    t.Commit();
                }
                //Catch with error message
                catch (Exception err)
                {
                    TaskDialog.Show("Error", err.Message);
                    t.RollBack();
                }
               
            }
                                    
        }

    }

}
```

Snip of this example inside Revit:

[Example photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mO8lz.png)

Comment: thanks a lot for such a broad solution including code!

Comment: It is definitely considerable but as of now it seems a little better to have the ability for the end user to 1)choose category(s) and after that - 2)choose parameters inside of it(them) to concatenate.Currently can't see any way to use retrieved chosen category that is now in the "selected" variable.Can't find an option to insert it to the elementCatagoryFilter to build collection.I assume that (1) has to be inside "class.cs" but not sure how to move it rightly.Any thoughts would be much appreciated.Haven't found an option to attach code so here's pic https://i.postimg.cc/WhXpC10k/selected.png